# Setting resizable to false shrinks window to point

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I am creating a GTK Window which, for various reasons, I wish to make non-resizable by the user. But invoking the set_resizable method on the window causes it to display with a size of 1 pixel by 1 pixel. (jn the code below, the window displays the expected size if the set-resizable line is commented out. It makes no difference which order the resize and set-resizable are invoked.) the Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Here is the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myarea.hpp"
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window win;
    win.set_title("DrawingArea");
    win.resize (600, 600);
    //win.set_resizable (false);

    MyArea area;
    win.add(area);
    area.show();

    Gtk::Main::run(win);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `win.set_size_request(600, 600);` instead of `resize`. I'm not 100% sure why your way doesn't work, but I think that `set_resizable(false)` undoes the effects of `resize` causing the window to revert to its default size request, which is as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you, ptomato. That's done the trick. (It would have been quite a while before I found that out from the documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

`Gtk::Window::set_default_size()` may also be useful